# textwrapping in silverlight 4 not working

Tags: silverlight-4.0, textblock, word-wrap

I want to do text wrap and show a vertical scroll bar when i have more than a line of text but the text is not getting wrapped at all. this is my xaml

```
<StackPanel Name="panel">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Background="Yellow">

                <TextBlock  Text="Text:" />
                <ScrollViewer                                    
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Height="33"                                    
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">                    
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Can someone tell me why the text won't wrap at end of screen ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening here is that your internal StackPanel (and every StackPanel) doesn't constraint its children to the "visible" space in the StackPanel. So, the scrollviewer feels like having unlimited space and so is the textblock. The Grid itself can do it:

```
<StackPanel Name="panel">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  Text="Text:" />
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Height="33"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                    Text="YourText" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Works pretty well now. I will have to change a few things now. Can you also tell me if it is possible to somehow make the scrollviewer the same height as a row in a grid so that it shows the scrollbar as soon as there is more text in the row? I hate hardcoding the height in the scrollviewer. 
Thank you

Comment: Sure... in my code sample, as the ScrollViewer is restricted by the Grid (exists an implicit Grid.Row="0"), the scroll viewer will be heighted (is that a word?) by the height of that row. So, all you have to do is `<RowDefinition Height="25" />`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not give the desired results. I added the height to the row like you said and removed the Height property from the ScrollViewer. However the scrollviewer still seems to get cut by the grid. I wish there was a way to attach a screen-shot but what I mean is that the bottom end of the scrollbar is not fully visible. I am only able to see half of the bottom end of the scrollbar.I would like it to fit in the row properly.

Comment: Well ok.. setting height to 35 solved it. Not sure why..probably that is the minimum height for a scrollviewer/my scrollviewer ?

Comment: Seems like the repeaters at the ends of the scroll bar are not sizable so yes, there should be a minimum.